# Migrated questions

Tags: discussion, migration, questions

I've seen a few untagged migrated questions turn up, and was wondering if this is the tip of an impending iceberg: All SharePoint questions ever asked anywhere being migrated to this site. Or is this just the standard level of everyday churn we should expect now we're an official SE site?

Sub-question: If this isn't the beginning of a bulk migration, should we be expecting such a migration in future?

Comment: Are you asking just to know? I think we should expect more SharePoint questions being migrated now that we are official.

Comment: Is there another reason to ask a question? :) Well, except rhetorical ones, like that one... I was going wide-eyed at the prospect of another bulk migration; I wanted to either confirm or deny its possibility, and find the alternative explanation for the untagged questions.

Comment: Ah yeah makes sense. I was just trying to figure out what your worry was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions from other sites in the network should only be migrated here if they are **on topic here** and **off topic for the original** site. If they are on topic for both sites then I think it's up to the OP, however there are differing opinions on this!

There are no plans for a bulk migration of older questions. That's something that could do more damage than good, e.g. reputations on both sites would be affected, and our site's quality may drop.

New questions can be migrated here, but it's not a requirement. I can't envisage auto-migrations occurring because some people want to keep only within one site (with one rep score that they care about).

Comment: By the way, the reason why some of these questions come over as [tag:untagged] is because they just contain the `sharepoint` tag which is banned on this site (as it doesn't make sense here).

Comment: Ok, thanks. That clears up a lot of questions in my mind. It does indeed make sense not to migrate the older questions.